# pdo mysql inserts one query twice

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

i have made just another very basic insert query, i want to insert just one row 3 columns.

```
public static function execute($params = null) // this is in my orm class, it does not extends or implements dpo or others so execute is not overrided
{
    try
    {
        self::processParams($params);
        self::$stmt = self::$mysql_conn->prepare(self::$query);
        self::$stmt->execute(self::$bind_params);
        return self::$mysql_conn->lastInsertId();
    }
    catch (PDOExecption $e)
    {
        $dbh->rollback();
        return false;
    }
}
```

with this qúery:

```
private $add_pcategory = "INSERT INTO pcategories (id, name, active) VALUES (NULL, :name, :active)";
```

i have more queries like this and all of them are working correctly with the same execute function.

I cannot find whats wrong with it.. tested with echo "Hey!" `before ->execute()` it does not prints it twice. so execute is loaded just once.

Where the insert is called:

```
<?php

/**
 * Description of products
 *
 * @author (c) erik
 */

/* TODO finish it, clean up, optimize and remove unused  */
class products extends system
{
    /* That was hard to write */
    /* TODO create needed db tables */
    private $add_quantity = "INSERT INTO quantity (id, itemtype, itemid, quantity) VALUES (NULL, :itemtype, :itemid, :quantity)";
    //Done
    // Product image
    private $add_image = "INSERT INTO tppimages (id, image, product) VALUES(NULL, :image, :product)";
    private $get_image = "SELECT * FROM tppimages WHERE image=:image AND product=:product";
    private $delete_image = "";
    // Product
    private $add_product = "INSERT INTO products (id, type, active) VALUES (NULL, :type, :active)";
    private $get_product = "SELECT p.*, pd.descr, pd.name, pd.price, pd.short, pd.size, pd.weight, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT img.filename ORDER BY img.filename) AS images, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT vid.videoid ORDER BY vid.videoid) AS videos FROM products p LEFT JOIN product_data pd ON (p.id = pd.id) LEFT JOIN tppimages pi ON (p.id = pi.product) LEFT JOIN images img ON (img.id = pi.image) LEFT JOIN tppvideos pv ON (p.id = pv.product) LEFT JOIN videos vid ON (vid.id = pv.video)  WHERE p.id=:id AND p.type=:type AND p.active=:active   ORDER BY p.id DESC";
    private $delete_product = "";
    private $get_products = "SELECT p.*, pd.name, pd.price, pd.short, pd.size, pd.weight, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT img.filename ORDER BY img.filename) AS images FROM products p LEFT JOIN product_data pd ON (p.id = pd.id) LEFT JOIN tppimages pi ON (p.id = pi.product) LEFT JOIN images img ON (img.id = pi.image) WHERE p.type=0 AND p.active=1 GROUP BY p.id ORDER BY p.id DESC LIMIT :from,:to";
    private $get_products_by_category = "SELECT p.*, pd.name, pd.price, pd.short, pd.size, pd.weight, tppc.pcategory, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT img.filename ORDER BY img.filename) AS images FROM products p LEFT JOIN product_data pd ON (p.id = pd.id) LEFT JOIN tppimages pi ON (p.id = pi.product) LEFT JOIN images img ON (img.id = pi.image) LEFT JOIN tppcategories tppc ON (p.id = tppc.product) LEFT JOIN pcategories pc ON (pc.id = tppc.pcategory) WHERE p.type=0 AND p.active=1 AND tppc.pcategory=:category GROUP BY p.id ORDER BY p.id DESC LIMIT :from,:to";
    private $add_product_data = "INSERT INTO product_data (id, name) VALUES (:id, :name)";
    private $add_to_pcategory = "INSERT INTO tppcategories (id, pcategory, product) VALUES (:id, :pcategory, :product)";
    // Sub product
    private $add_subproduct = "INSERT INTO tpproducts (id, mainprod, subprod) VALUES (NULL, :mainprod, :subprod)";
    private $get_subproducts = "SELECT pd.* FROM tpproducts tpps JOIN product_data pd ON (tpps.subprod = pd.id) WHERE tpps.mainprod=:id";
    private $delete_subproduct = "DELETE FROM tpproducts WHERE mainprod=:mainprod AND subprod=:subprod";
    // Product categories
    private $delete_pcategories = "DELETE FROM pcategories WHERE id=:id";
    private $add_pcategory = "INSERT INTO pcategories (id, name, active) VALUES (NULL, :name, :active)";
    private $get_pcategory = "SELECT * FROM pcategories WHERE id=:id";
    private $is_pcategory = "SELECT * FROM pcategories WHERE name=:name";
    /* DOTO add category images */
    private $get_categories = "SELECT c.* FROM pcategories c ORDER BY c.name ASC";

    /**
     * 
     * @param type $xhr boolean, means that module was loaded from ajax request to be able to avoid loading templates
     */
    public function init($xhr = false) /* TODO add access level */
    {
        if (!$xhr)
        {

            //  $this->addProductImages(6, array("1", "2", "3"));

            $this->addProductCategory("Tepelné kamery"); //Here i am testing it,

            /* $this->addProductCategory("Ultrazvukové");
              $this->addProductCategory("Testovacie");
              $this->addProductCategory("Údené klobásy");
             * */
            $this->initTpl("header.tpl");
            $this->initTpl("top_panel.tpl");
            $this->initTpl("left_panel.tpl");
            $this->loadTemplate();
            $this->initTpl("right_panel.tpl");
            $this->initTpl("bottom_panel.tpl");
            $this->initTpl("footer.tpl");
        }
        else
        {

        }
    }

// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" product ">
    public function getProducts($category = null)
    {
        $pDTO = new pDTO();
        $pDTO->setActive(true);
        $pDTO->setCategory($category);
        return orm::getInstance()->setQuery((is_null($category) ? $this->get_products : $this->get_products_by_category))->setDto($pDTO)->select(array("from" => "0", "to" => "30"));
    }

    public function getProduct($prodid)
    {
        $pDTO = new pDTO();
        $pDTO->setId($prodid);
        $pDTO->setActive(true);
        $pDTO->setType("0");
        return orm::getInstance()->setQuery($this->get_product)->setDto($pDTO)->select();
    }

    public function updateProduct()
    {

    }

    public function addProduct()
    {
        $pDTO = new pDTO();
        $pDTO->setActive(true);
        $pDTO->setType("1");
        $pDTO->setName("Hello product");
        $result = orm::getInstance()->setQuery($this->add_product)->setDto($pDTO)->execute();
        if ($result != false)
        {
            $pDTO->setId($result);
            $result = orm::getInstance()->setQuery($this->add_product_data)->setDTO($pDTO)->execute();
        }
    }

    public function getProductItems($prodid)
    {
        $pDTO = new pDTO();
        $pDTO->setId($prodid);
        $pDTO->setActive(true);
        $pDTO->setType("1");

        return orm::getInstance()->setQuery($this->get_subproducts)->setDto($pDTO)->select();
    }

    public function addSubProducts($items)
    {

    }

    public function addSubProduct($id)
    {
        $pDTO = new pDTO();
        $pDTO->setActive(true);
        $pDTO->setMainprod($id);
        $pDTO->setType("1");
        $pDTO->setName("Ethernet kápel");
        $pDTO->setShort("50 metrov");
        $subprod_id = orm::getInstance()->setQuery($this->add_product)->setDto($pDTO)->execute();
        if ($subprod_id != false)
        {
            $pDTO->setSubprod($subprod_id);
            $tpprod_id = orm::getInstance()->setQuery($this->add_subproduct)->setDTO($pDTO)->execute();

            if ($tpprod_id == false)
            {
                //delete subprod here
            }
        }
    }

    public function addProductItemQuantity($item, $quantity)
    {
        $qyDTO = new qyDTO();
        $qyDTO->setItemid($item);
        $qyDTO->setItemtype("1");
        $qyDTO->setQuantity($quantity);
        return orm::getInstance()->setQuery($this->add_quantity)->setDto($qyDTO)->execute();
    }

// </editor-fold>
//
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Product Category ">
    public function getProductCategories()
    {
        $pcDTO = new pCategoryDTO();
        return orm::getInstance()->setQuery($this->get_categories)->setDto($pcDTO)->select();
    }

    public function addProductCategory($categoryname)
    {
        $pcDTO = new pCategoryDTO();
        $pcDTO->setName($categoryname);
 /* TODO comment out when, query for single row insert will not insert 2 rows */
        // $exists = orm::getInstance()->setQuery($this->is_pcategory)->setDto($pcDTO)->select();
        // if ($exists == false) 
        // {
        $pcDTO->setActive(true);
        return orm::getInstance()->setQuery($this->add_pcategory)->setDto($pcDTO)->execute();
        // }
    }

    public function deleteProductCategory()
    {

    }

// </editor-fold>

    public function addProductImages($product, $images)
    {
        $tppiDTO = new tppimagesDTO();
        $tppiDTO->setProduct($product);
        foreach ($images as $image)
        {
            $tppiDTO->setImage($image);
            $exists = orm::getInstance()->setQuery($this->get_image)->setDto($tppiDTO)->select();
            if ($exists == false)
            {
                orm::getInstance()->setQuery($this->add_image)->setDto($tppiDTO)->execute();
            }
        }
    }

    public function updateProductImage()
    {

    }

    public function deleteProductImage()
    {

    }

    public function addProductVideo()
    {

    }

    public function updateProductVideo()
    {

    }

    public function deleteProductVideo()
    {

    }

    private function loadTemplate()
    {
        if (!$this->getGet("identifier") && !$this->getGet("category"))
        {
            $this->assignVar("pccategories", $this->getProductCategories());
            $this->initTpl("products_categories.tpl");
        }
        elseif ($this->getGet("category"))
        {
            $this->assignVar("products", $this->getProducts($this->getGet("category")));
            $this->initTpl("product_list.tpl");
        }
        else
        {
            $this->assignVar("productitems", $this->getProductItems($this->getGet("identifier")));
            $this->assignVar("products", $this->getProduct($this->getGet("identifier")));
            $this->initTpl("product.tpl");
        }
    }

}
```

And this is my ORM module where everything happens.

```
<?php

/**
 * Description of orm
 *
 * @author (c) erik
 */
class orm extends kernel
{

    private static $instance, $bind_params, $bind_params_custom, $fields, $attrs, $imp_arr, $query;
    public static $stmt, $mysql_conn;

    /* TODO complete cleanup for new logic */

    public static function execute($params = null)
    {
        try
        {
            self::processParams($params);
            self::$stmt = self::$mysql_conn->prepare(self::$query);
            self::$stmt->execute(self::$bind_params);
            return self::$mysql_conn->lastInsertId();
        }
        catch (PDOExecption $e)
        {
            $dbh->rollback();
            return false;
        }
    }

    public static function select($params = null)
    {
        try
        {
            self::processParams($params);
            self::$stmt = self::$mysql_conn->prepare(self::$query);
            self::$stmt->execute(self::$bind_params);
            return self::$stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        }
        catch (PDOExecption $e)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    private static function processParams($params)
    {
        foreach (self::$fields as $key => $value)
        {
            if (strpos(self::$query, ":{$key}"))
            {
                self::$bind_params[$key] = $value;
            }
        }
        if (!is_null($params))
        {
            foreach ($params as $key => $value)
            {
                self::$bind_params_custom[$key] = $value;
            }
            self::$bind_params = array_merge(self::$bind_params, self::$bind_params_custom);
        }
    }

    public static function delete($pdo)
    {
        self::setDto($pdo);
    }

// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" set, construct, instance, destruct ">
    public static function setDto($dto)
    {
        self::$fields = get_object_vars($dto);
        return self::$instance;
    }

    public static function setQuery($query)
    {
        self::$query = $query;
        return self::$instance;
    }

    public static function getInstance()
    {
        if (is_null(self::$instance))
        {
            self::$instance = new orm();
        }
        self::$bind_params = array();
        self::$imp_arr = array();
        self::$bind_params_custom = array();
        self::$query = "";
        return self::$instance;
    }

    function __construct()
    {
        self::$attrs = array(PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true, PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES utf8', PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false, PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        self::$mysql_conn = new PDO("mysql:host=" . self::$config["mysql"]["host"] . ";port=" . self::$config["mysql"]["port"] . ";dbname=" . self::$config["mysql"]["database"] . "", self::$config["mysql"]["username"], self::$config["mysql"]["password"], self::$attrs);
    }

    function __destruct()
    {

    }

// </editor-fold>
}
```

I cant imagine whats wrong, add product works, add image works, add pcategory inserts 2 rows instead of one.

Search for: `addProductCategory($categoryname)` if you dont want to search in whole code.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have disabled mysql start at bootime, rebooted started manually and now it works :D